# Jaxb question on root elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to create some xml to send off to another application in the below format and I'm trying to use jaxb.  There is always only 1 occurrence of bar.  Is there a way to do this or is it invalid xml because it has 2 root elements and the other application will need to change how it accepts the xml?

```
<FOO>
 <BAR>
  <id>1</id>
  <POINTS>111</POINTS>
  <CODE>123</CODE>
 </BAR>
</FOO>
```

Comment: This is perfectly valid. What problem are you having?

Comment: Right, it does not have 2 roots (<FOO> is the root element). But as to JAXB, if there is property "BAR" which does not take a list, JAXB will not be able to figure out how to use such XML.

Comment: Per the specs I have that is the exact xml I should be sending, and I can't find a way to get the bar in the xml.  There is only 1 occurrence of the 3 elements in bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are a couple of approaches:

**Standard JAXB**

The following will work with any JAXB implementation (Metro, [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), JaxMe, etc). You could create the element "*FOO*", and then marshal your instance of Bar into it.  The code below how to demonstrate this using StAX (it could also be done with DOM or SAX):

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamWriter xsw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
        xsw.writeStartDocument();
        xsw.writeStartElement("FOO");

        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setId(1);
        bar.setPoints(111);
        bar.setCode(123);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bar.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(bar, xsw);

        xsw.writeEndElement();
        xsw.writeEndDocument();
        xsw.close();
    }

}
```

**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**

If you happen to be using [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), then you can use the @XmlPath extension (I'm the MOXy tech lead).  Your Bar class would look like:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="FOO")
@XmlType(propOrder={"id", "points", "code"})
public class Bar {

    private int id;
    private int points;
    private int code;

    @XmlPath("BAR/id/text()")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlPath("BAR/POINTS/text()")
    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    @XmlPath("BAR/CODE/text()")
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}
```

For more information see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

Comment: I got the correct xml formatted correctly using the first code example, now I just need to figure out how to compare the XMLStreamWriter to my expected xml so my test will pass.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Scott - Not problem, if this answered your questions please consider marking it as the accepted answer.  This flags to other users that you have found the answer you are looking for.